# Scrolling not triggered when keypad is showing in NesetedScrollView

Tags: android, android-design-library

I have the following layout which basically displays two editTexts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="global.sti.attendance.LogInActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_log_in">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="150dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">
        <EditText
            style="@style/TextField"
            android:id="@+id/userNameET"
            android:hint="Enter username"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_textfield"/>
        <EditText
            style="@style/TextField"
            android:id="@+id/passwordET"
            android:hint="Enter password"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_textfield"/>
        <Button
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log-in"
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:width="180dp" />
        <Button
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGN-UP!"
            android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:width="180dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is my activity_log_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="global.sti.attendance.LogInActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_log_in" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my TextField style:

```
<style name="TextField">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">40dp</item>
</style>
```

The problem is when I click on one of the editTexts and the keypad is showing, it blocks my views, I would expect the NestedScrollView will allow me to scroll up but it does not.

What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the closing </NestedScrollView> tag in your example btw.

Comment: I'm testing your layout and I can scroll without a problem, could you post your activity_log_in.xml and "@style/TextField" styles please?

Comment: Also it might just be the fixed padding you have: `android:paddingTop="150dp"`

Comment: @Evin1_ ok ill post my activity_log_in and note that i have </NestedScrollView> just accidentally omitted it.

Comment: @Evin1_ i added your requests on my question. Please see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your activity in the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

---

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LogInActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    <!-- Intent-filters if any -->
</activity>
```

Comment: ok ill try this and get back to you later if this worked. Thanks!